# Similarity finding best grammar

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

If you had the text `abcxxcde`, how would you go about counting the number of similarities?

Would there be be `1` because one type of letter (`x`) is the same or `2` because there are two letters that match?

Comment: Hello, Richie....did you possibly post this on the wrong SE site?

Comment: I don't think so. This question asks if someone was given the text `abxxcde` what is the best way to count the similarities - would It be `1` or `2`

Comment: ...but that is not what we do here. This site is about the usage of English. Your question is about logic and programming.

Comment: There **is a** similarity between domestic cats and ocelots.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are 2 vowels and 6 consonants.

There are 6 types of letters, with 2 reoccurring, each twice (i.e., "c" and "x")

There are 8 letters wherein the same letter occurs consecutively once, for a total of 2 occurrences (i.e., "xx").

All the letters are lowercase.

There are no substrings which form common words.

> 

That said, I do not think this is the right site for what you're looking for.

Comment: "That said, I do not think this is the right site"...then please do not answer it. That just makes it more difficult to remove the Q. And now that the OP has ticked your answer, you cannot remove it.

Comment: You never know when something might be useful, even something which appears completely useless. Maybe especially so in those cases.

Comment: Please review the [site standards and guidelines for proper questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) . This question so does not belong here.

Comment: I did and still disagree, but I see your point. Luke 23:34

Comment: Might I suggest St. John.."Let it be"?